# How can I stabilize floating labels in React using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a registration form using **React** and **Tailwind CSS**. When I focus on an input form, the label slides up. There is no problem until here. However, when I focus on another input, the label of the input I previously focused on becomes a placeholder. That is, the label that has *just* moved up returns to its place. My codes are as follows:

```
<div className="relative mb-4">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="username"
                name="username"
                value={formData.username}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="peer p-3 h-10 w-full border-b-2 border-gray-300 text-gray-900 placeholder-transparent focus-within:outline-none focus-within:border-rose-600"
                placeholder=""
                required
              />
              <label
                htmlFor="username"
                className={`absolute left-1 top-2 transition-all text-gray-400 ${formData.username.length > 0 ? 'text-md' : 'text-base'
                  } ${formData.username.length > 0 ? 'text-gray-400' : ''
                  } peer-focus-within:left-0 peer-focus-within:-top-6 peer-focus-within:text-gray-700 peer-focus-within:text-md peer-focus-within:text-bold`}
              >
                Username
              </label>
            </div>
```

Screenshots

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

[image: The problem is here]

The problem is clearly visible in the fourth screenshot. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

I tried to perform some checks using template strings and ternary operator but I still couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon if I misunderstood your problem but it seems that you want it the label to stop changing its position after the user is ready. Currently, your effect of changing its position is described in the

```
peer-focus-within:-top-6
```

But the problem comes when the focus is taken out of. After that happens, the focus within rule doesn't apply and the original style takes over.

There are few ways to tackle this. I would suggest that you would simplify your styling logic to follow the username length as so:

```
  className={`absolute transition-all ${formData.username.length === 0 ? 'left-1 top-2 text-gray-400 peer-focus-within:left-0 peer-focus-within:-top-6 peer-focus-within:text-gray-700 peer-focus-within:text-md peer-focus-within:text-bold' : 'left-0 -top-6 text-gray-700 text-md text-bold'}`}
```

The classname would change permanently to the same after the transition has changed so it wouldn't change back